# Opposite term of apothem

Tags: geometry

If the apothem of a regulat polygon is the shortest distance from the center, what would the longest distance be called?

Answer (score 0):

This distance is often called the "radius" of the polygon, because it is the radius of the polygon's circumcircle--that is, the distance from the center to a vertex.